# Создание большого количества табов

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, recyclerview

Необходимо создать, к примеру, 10-20 табов с различной информацией, которую они выводят с помощью `RecyclerView` по одному принципу (т.е. через один адаптер). Как это реализовать? Под каждый таб необходимо реализовывать собственный `Fragment` и `layout` соответственно c определенным в нем `RecyclerView`? Или это можно обойти каким-то способом? И все это конечно же прикручено через `ViewPager` и вкладки листаются между собой с помощью `swipe`.

## update

Хорошо, но вопрос я задавал почему..

Есть у меня самый обычный `ViewPagerAdapter`

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

И добавляю я в него табы тоже обычно:

```
    adapter.addFragment(new PageFragment().newInstance("Понедельник"), "Понедельник");
    adapter.addFragment(new PageFragment().newInstance("Вторник"), "Вторник");
    adapter.addFragment(new PageFragment().newInstance("Среда"), "Среда");
    adapter.addFragment(new PageFragment().newInstance("Четверг"), "Четверг");
    adapter.addFragment(new PageFragment().newInstance("Пятница"), "Пятница");
```

По сути, на обоих табах сейчас должна отображаться одна и та же информация, но отображается она только на одном - на первом. Код с данными срабатывает 2 раза (что логично), а отображается информация только на "Таб 1". С чем это может быть связано?

## update 2

Да даже если взять обычные TextView и передавать им какие-то строки.. Одно и тоже. Отредактировал код добавления фрагмента. + Добавил код самого фрагмента

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    String page;

    TextView textView;
    String string = "дефолт";

    public PageFragment newInstance(String string) {
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("STRING", string);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        page = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("link");
        Log.d("WHALETAG", "onStart()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("WHALETAG", "onCreate()");
        string = getArguments().getString("STRING");
        textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_test);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("WHALETAG", "onCreateView()" + textView);
        try {
            textView.setText(string);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_numerator, container, false);
    }
}
```

а в итоге получается вот так.. Данные он хватает как-то сумбурно все. Периодически кидает `NullPointerException` при попытке засеттить текст в `textView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё ещё недостаточно информации для ответа. Что за данные, как они получаются, как отображаются - не ясно. По сути, передавая фрагменты в адаптер вы их содаёте одинаковыми. Видимо, вам надо как-то указывать фрагментам, что они немного разные. Например, передавая им начальные параметры через аргументы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что вы из фрагмета ищете текствью в активити. Так не надо. Надо создавать разметку фрагмента в онкреатевью и в ней, в разметке фрагмента, ставить в текствью текст. Просто почтайте немного для чего метод онкреатевью

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял досадную ошибку свою. Все работает отлично. Как всегда, спасибо Вам за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если адаптер один и данные для него однотипны, то создайте 1 фрагмент.

Этот фрагмент отображайте в `ViewPager`.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, посмотри пожалуйста